# How to set VideoView Background with image in Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

Is there any way to set the VideoView Background with image, so that when the video is played the black portion on both side (left & right) shows the image as set on background. I have tried but the video cannot be seen, it shows only the background image, though the video is played, its sound can be heard.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/header">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Chapter-1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></VideoView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/overTitle" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text=" text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/videoView1"
        android:background="@drawable/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:id="@+id/menu_btn" android:layout_below="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Menu"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/videoView1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/videoView1"
            android:background="@drawable/menu"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_below="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="High"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/videoView1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/videoView1"
            android:background="@drawable/menu"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_below="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="CC"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/videoView1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/videoView1"
            android:background="@drawable/menu"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/exit_btn" android:layout_below="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Exit"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/videoView1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/videoView1"
            android:background="@drawable/menu"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can adapt the size of your video view to the video frame size. so you don't have the black stripes on the left and right side.

if you set a background image you have to set the video view on the top of the layer model. otherwise the image covers your video view and you cannot see the video.

**EDIT**

to set the size of the video view you have to declare it as an object in your layout and not as layout itself.

here is an example:

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>

        <VideoView android:id="@+id/VideoView" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" ...(here you can set further setting of the video view)></VideoView>
        <Button android:text= ...></Button>
        <Button android:text=...></Button>          
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks you. all for ur kind response... I have added the xml code can you please take a look

Comment: i've edited my post with a small example. you can also set the size and position of the videoview in your source code with the videoview.layout() method.